# How to split string using a whole word as separator?

Tags: string, lua, lua-patterns

Is there a way to split string like:

```
"importanttext1 has gathered importanttext2 from stackoverflow."
```

I want to grab anything before the word `"has"`, and just want to grab the one word after `"gathered"`, so it doesn't include `"from stackoverflow."`. I want to be left with 2 variables that cointain `importanttext1` and `importanttext2`

Comment: Lua is not an acronym. It's simply Lua, not LUA.

Comment: You mean: get the word before `has` and the word after `gathered`? I don't get it. And show what you have tried.

Comment: I imagine Lua's regex would suffice for something like this, but your question is still unclear. Please elaborate.

Comment: sorry i was unclear i changed the wording a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
local str = "importanttext1 has gathered importanttext2 from stackoverflow."
local s1 = str:match("(.+)has")
local s2 = str:match("gathered%s+(%S+)")
print(s1)
print(s2)
```

Note that `"%s"` matches a whitespace character while `"%S"` matches a non-whitespace character.

Comment: what about: `local s1,s2 = str:match'(.+)%s+has gathered%s+(.+)%s+from'`? would be faster I think